# Using ESP8266 to program Arduino by serial comm

Tags: arduino-uno, esp8266

Since ESP8266 can self program on wifi, can we use it to program arduino too with the binary sent via wifi? my arduino is connected with reset+RX+TX pins and shared power.
Has this been already done?

Answer (score 0):

If you use Linux, you can use a simple [Telnet to Serial sketch](https://github.com/jandrassy/lab/blob/master/AvrDudeTelnet/AvrDudeTelnet.ino) in esp8266 to upload with avrdude to Uno over esp8266. Only on Linux can avrdude use telnet to do a serial upload.

For upload from IDE on any OS there is [JeeLabs ESP Link firmware](https://github.com/jeelabs/esp-link) for the esp8266.

Comment: plenty of ways on other os to patch things so arduino looks to be connected over serial as far as avrdude is concerned- for example com0com makes virtual serial ports...

Comment: @Abel, did you test it?

Comment: haven't done it for avrdude yet, but i did have the need to do something similar for a serial user interface program to connect to a stream that had to be encapsulated by ssh first.

Comment: tested with pi in the middle (avrdude-com0com-customExe-pi-customProgram-uno).  gotchas found: bootloader baud, and stable re-entry to bootloader.  no reason to believe any other program attempting this over serial would behave differently.  i implemented re-entry via usb port poweroff and poweron via rpi uhubctl, but it might be possible with hardware (reset pin), a modified bootloader, or crashing? the main on command (casting 0 to a function pointer and calling it).

Comment: @Abel, my sketch linked in the answer resets the target at new telnet connection. what problem with baud rate?

Comment: i didnt use your sketch or telnet.  Just wanted to prove you are not limited to avrdude linux to get the job done- for me avrdude thought it was talking over serial and uploaded just fine.  Can make a connection between avrdude and the nets with other programs.